# mongoose .save() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, backend

facing error `.save()` is not a function.

I have done it before but this time I dont understand why it is giving me this error. Athough I can query data from the database but it keeps giving me this error

code:

```
router.post("/password-reset", (req,res) => {
  signMeUp.findOneAndUpdate({email:req.body.resetmail})
    .then(nuser => {
      nuser.username,
      nuser.email,
      nuser.password = req.body.psd,
      nuser.image 

    })

    signMeUp.save().then(()=>{
      console.log("password changed  successfully !")
    })
})
```

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate()` requires two arguments : 1. conditions, 2. update. And it does not return a saveable (savable?) document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the second parameter of [`Model.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) function to pass the properties you want to update:

```
router.post("/password-reset", (req,res) => {
  signMeUp.findOneAndUpdate({ email: req.body.resetmail }, { password: req.body.psd })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("password changed  successfully !")
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to await for the promise to be resolved because now it's returning a promise

```js
//Don't forget to make the function async

const nuser = await signMeUp.findOneAndUpdate({email:req.body.resetmail})
 


  nuser.password = req.body.psd
   

  await nuser.save();
```

or use .then()

```js
ignMeUp.findOneAndUpdate({email:req.body.resetmail})
  .then(nuser => {

    nuser.username,
    nuser.email,
    nuser.password = req.body.psd,
    nuser.image 
    nuser.save()

  })
```

Comment: You can't `await` AND `.then()`. You go `await` style OR promise style, not both at the same time.

Comment: @Ahmed Gaafer   it sitills give the same error

Comment: (node:13300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: signMeUp.save is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Here's the await style with Mongoose :

```
router.post("/password-reset", async (req, res) => { // add async so you can await inside
    const nuser = await signMeUp.findOne({ email: req.body.resetmail }).exec()

    // Do some stuff

    await nuser.save();

    console.log("password changed  successfully !")
    
    res.end()
})
```

Or in one go with `findOneAndUpdate` :

```
router.post("/password-reset", async (req, res) => { // add async so you can await inside
    await signMeUp.findOneAndUpdate({ email: req.body.resetmail },
            { someField : "some update"})
            .exec()

    console.log("password changed  successfully !")
    
    res.end()
})
```